# Adding manually an error in the nosetests in try - except

Tags: python, nose

My problem is that running tests with the help of nosetests. When I use try-except and there is a bug, nosetests displays the dot character, which means it has succeeded. Can you set an option in except to force the F or E character? Have you encountered such a problem?
For example 54 tests (7 fail), but I have all correct.

```
.....................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 54 tests in 724.380s

OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you try and except an error you actually state that it is fine to have an error, so

1. remove your try except

> OR

2. put a raise statement in your except clause... this will raise the last error

> short example

```
try:
    assert False
except AssertionError as intended_exception:
    print(intended_exception)
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test isn't failing, even though you think it sould. Perhaps it's not even running - this is why [red-green-refactor](https://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Red-Green-Refactor.html) is a good approach.

Try putting `assert False` into your test. If you still see no failure, your test definitely isn't running.

If this does cause nose to see an error, you'll have to show us your test and production code if we are to help you.